# Why does python-ldap code raise the Exception ldap.REFERRAL?

Tags: python, exception, ldap, python-ldap

I'm trying to use the `python-ldap` library to connect to an `Active Directory` Server.
I'm using the code found in [this link](https://gist.github.com/DiegoQueiroz/d35d8c8f52b58df2f39b4eed0c2c9520).

The following code works correctly:

```
con = ldap.initialize(uri, bytes_mode=False)
con.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
con.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)  # required for AD authentication
con.simple_bind_s(bindDN, bindPW)
print("Authentication success!")
```

With correct credentials (in the variables `bindDN` and `bindPW`) the execution of the code enables the connection to my AD server so it prints the successfully message `Authentication success!` that is the last instruction of the previous snippet of code.

When I try to execute the code below, the last instruction `con.result3`, raise the ldap.REFERRAL Exception.

```
# optional, but reduce the number of supported control, since only this one will be parsed
known_ldap_resp_ctrls = {
    SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType: SimplePagedResultsControl,
}

# instantiate the control that will make the paged results
# it carries the page cookie (initially empty, to request the first page)
req_ctrl = SimplePagedResultsControl(
    criticality=True,
    size=pagesize,
    cookie=''
)

# query next page, asynchronous
msgid = con.search_ext(
    baseDN,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    filterstr,
    attrlist=attrlist,
    serverctrls=[req_ctrl]
)

try:
    con.result3(msgid, timeout=timeout, resp_ctrl_classes=known_ldap_resp_ctrls)
except ldap.REFERRAL as ex:
    print("REFERRAL Exception --> " + str(ex))
```

When the Exception is raised the catch block of `ldap.REFERRAL Exception`, prints the following message:

```
REFERRAL Exception --> {'msgtype': 101, 'msgid': 2, 'result': 10, 'desc': 'Referral', 'ctrls': [('1.2.840.113556.1.4.319', 0, b'0\x84\x00\x00\x00\x05\x02\x01\x00\x04\x00')], 'info': 'Referral:\nldap://domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local'}
```

I'm completely stuck on this Exception.

Someone could help me to find where is the problem?

Thanks

---

If I execute the same query by the utility `ldapsearch`, it works correctly and the AD Server sends the requested data.

Comment: If applicable, opt out of referral: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146390/python-how-to-setup-python-ldap-to-ignore-referrals

Comment: @Lior Pollak Thanks but if I add the tips present in [your suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146390/python-how-to-setup-python-ldap-to-ignore-referrals) the code execution raise yet a REFERRAL exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous code I have done a mistake in the setting of variable `baseDN` which had the wrong **example** value `DC=domain,DC=local`.

`baseDN` variable is used by the function `search_ext()`. Here is a portion of the code already shown in my question which uses `baseDN`:

```
# query next page, asynchronous
msgid = con.search_ext(
  baseDN,
  ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
  filterstr,
  attrlist=attrlist,
  serverctrls=[req_ctrl]
)
```

In fact the content of the field `info` of the Exception message reported in the question is:

```
'info': 'Referral:\nldap://domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local'
```

In this part of the error message I have noted the values`DC=domain,DC=local`.

Setting the correct value of the variable `baseDN`, the LDAP server responds to the query with the data requested.

### A bit of confusion around the *LDAP referral concept*

Find the solution of this problem (which appears as a inattention) was not easy because looking for information about  the *LDAP referral concept* I have found for example this [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/overview.html) which links `LDAP referral` to alias.

Instead this is a useful link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/ldap-integration-fails-with-ldap-error-code-10-658735957.html which has suggested me where to search the problem.